# htaccess configure rewrite rules for local, wip domain and prodution domain in the same file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to configure my htaccess with rules for local developemnt, wip domain and production domain, so i dont need to edit when I test the project in these domains.

I think I am close, but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

#PRODUCTION
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?PRODUCTION_DOMAIN\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [S=3]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#WIP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?WIP_DOMAIN\.org$
RewriteRule ^ - [S=3]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wip/PROJECT_NAME/index.php [L]

#LOCAL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /PROJECT_NAME/index.php [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just create different vhost for different projects. That way the paths will be the same. So you havee e.g. `projectname.com`, `projectname.wipdomain.com` and `projectname.local`

Answer (score 1):

I used to run my apache server with -DLOCALDEV flag and then my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<IfDefine LOCALDEV>
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
        // any local specific goes here
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't solve my problem with the wip server, because I cant set an enviroment flag on that domain.